# IE Link error - "The current webpge is trying to open a site on your intranet. do you want to allow this?"

Tags: internet-explorer

Ok, we are getting a freaky error on our website.

We have a members section on our website that requires login.

On that page we have a link that goes to a partner company.

https://www.examplepartnersite.com/mycompany

Our website is also https.

When you click on the link it says: "The current webpge is trying to open a site on your intranet. do you want to allow this?"

Current site: https://www.examplepartnersite.com
Intranet site: http://www.mycompany.com

If I click "Yes", it takes me to the home page of my website.

If I click "No" it takes me the default page "Internet explorer cannot display the web page."

Chrome and FireFox seem to be working fine.

..AND I am assuming that this would only happen internally since it is referencing our "Intranet"...

I have no idea what would be causing this...???

Anyone got any ideas?

Thx